# Read data iteratively from DynamoDB inside a Step Functions workflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-step-functions

I am new to coding and learning about AWS services. I am trying to fetch data iteratively from a DynamoDB table in a Step Functions workflow. For Example, say for a book ID I want to check the names of customers that purchased the book. I am primarily trying to do practice using Map state and try to integrate with DDB.

I created a DDB table with `id` as partition key and added `cust_name1` and `cust_name2` as attributes for multiple customers of a book. Now in my Step Functions, I want to use a Map state to query how many people have that book ID. Is this possible? Or is there a better way to use Map state for this scenario?

I am able to do this in a Task state, but trying to figure out how to use Map state for this scenario.

```json
{
  "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
  "StartAt": "DynamoDB Get Book Purchases",
  "States": {
    "DynamoDB Get Book Purchases": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::dynamodb:getItem",
      "Parameters": {
        "TableName": "get-book-data",
        "Key": {
          "id": {
            "S": "121-11-2436"
          }
        }
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.DynamoDB",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map (in Step Functions) is designed to apply a function on each of the elements of an array or list. `Count` is an aggregation function and therefore, using it as part of `Map` is not that useful.

For your exercise, you can try to allow users to buy multiple books, where the `Map` functions will check the availability of each of the books in your inventory.